# Change of dispayed page html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 2 HTLM webpages with links [www.testme.com/a.html](http://www.testme.com/a.html) and [www.testme.com/b.html](http://www.testme.com/b.html). Now, I would like the link [www.testme.com/b.html](http://www.testme.com/b.html) to be displayed when a.html is open. Is that possible?

If it's not possible, maybe I have another approach: In a.html, I have share button to social media with code below. When choosing one button associated with one social media, I would like b.html to be shared instead of a.html.

```
<!-- AddToAny BEGIN -->
<div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_default_style">
<a class="a2a_dd" href="https://www.addtoany.com/share"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_facebook"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_twitter"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_email"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_whatsapp"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_linkedin"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_google_gmail"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_telegram"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_skype"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_sms"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_viber"></a>
</div>
<script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
<!-- AddToAny END -->
```

Comment: Hello, can you clarify your questions, is not entirely clear what are you looking to do, are you asking if you can add a link inside of page2.html to page1.html? Also you have two questions in this thread, I would suggest you to just have one question and create a second one in another post.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the content of [www.testme.com/b.html](http://www.testme.com/b.html) to be shown on  [www.testme.com/a.html](http://www.testme.com/a.html) when it's open.

In that scenario, you're able to use an HTML iframe for that.

Example:

```html
<iframe src="b.html" height="500" width="500"></iframe>
```

More information about HTML iframes can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp).